# Git: C++ format agnostic annotations

Tags: c++, git, formatting, diff

Is there a way to exclude just formatting changes in git? I mean git tools provide a way to ignore whitespace changes - that's ok. I'm interested in C++ code (but the question could be generalized to any format). The C++ standard provides some freedom in code formatting. But that can make orientation in git history really messy if there are changes just in formatting and not in the functionality of the code.

I can imagine some of the git tools doing the work on some kind of "normalized" code (possibly output of other tools - like `clang -format`)

Is that somehow possible? Are there better approaches?

(would be nice if the diff/annotate/etc. tools would run on the "normalized symbolic representation" - I know, that would require Git to "understand the code" and not be running on the plain-text, but I'm sure it could be solved by 3rd party "normalizers" - or maybe it's not concern of Git at all and it's up to the IDE - don't know)

Comment: White spaces are one thing, code formatting are something else. Brackets, multi-lines, column length... The least bad option is to run clang-format as a pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would be nice if the diff/annotate/etc. tools would run on the "normalized symbolic representation

Provide a tool that produces that from your actual source, and Git will indeed diff the normalized form for you.  Specify `diff=mydiff` as a file attribute, either tracked in the published history as a `.gitattributes` entry or locally for your own use in `.git/info/attributes`, and configure `diff.mydiff.textconv` to be your canonicalizer, e.g. `clang-format`, which if given a filename arg produces the result on stdout exactly as git likes.  [The feature's built for text diffs of binary files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_performing_text_diffs_of_binary_files) but "binary" here really just means "a format that's inconvenient for diffing".